# svn: always create new repository in some root dir

Tags: svn, repository, root

I've just installed Subversion on a Windows XP Pro box. Can I configure SVN in such a way that it always uses the same root directory to create a new repository with:

```
svnadmin create
```

?

So that if I do:

```
svnadmin create myrepository
```

it will automatically create a repository in for instance:

```
D:\data\svn\repositories\myrepository
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We have script (which we named `new-repo`) in the system path that does just that. In fact, it not only creates a repository in a designated global location (which is what you are asking about) but it also creates a `/trunk`, `/branches` and `/tags` directory and sets up a common `svn:ignore` on `/trunk`. In our case, we also have some pre and post-commit triggers so the script automatically copies them in place automatically.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html), no.

> The path argument to svnadmin is just a regular filesystem path and not a URL like the svn client program uses when referring to repositories.
>   Both svnadmin and svnlook are considered server-side utilities—they are used on the machine where the repository resides to examine or modify aspects of the repository, and are in fact unable to perform tasks across a network.
>   A common mistake made by Subversion newcomers is trying to pass URLs (even “local”  `file:// ones`) to these two programs.

Only a custom script could achieve what you want.